# How to take a picture on another device

Tags: php, mysql, objective-c, iphone, json

I want to learn how to let users take pictures on other devices.

My question is that since the below, user taken idPhoto is connected to the iduser field , would it be possible to get the deviceid of the user that posted the photo and asynchronously run snapStillImage on that users device on tap considering that it is currently the very IdPhoto that performs the segue selector to a full screen image of that photo? The current methods for the segue to full screen after a pic is tapped are below. I want to know if its possible to let users take pictures of other users of their choosing. I want this to happen when selecting a posted photo. All posted photos are connected to `IdUser`s in the database as well as `IdPhoto`.

```
  -(void)didSelectPhoto:(PhotoView*)sender {
//photo selected - show it full screen
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ShowPhoto" sender:[NSNumber numberWithInt:sender.tag]];
}
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
if ([@"ShowPhoto" compare: segue.identifier]==NSOrderedSame) {
    StreamPhotoScreen* streamPhotoScreen = segue.destinationViewController;
    streamPhotoScreen.IdPhoto = sender;
}
}
```

StreamPhoto screen, the current result of a user tapping a jpeg thumb of an image taken and uploaded which shows a pic in full screen in a this view controller.

```
#import "StreamPhotoScreen.h"
#import "API.h"
@implementation StreamPhotoScreen
@synthesize IdPhoto;
-(void)viewDidLoad {
API* api = [API sharedInstance];
//load the caption of the selected photo
[api commandWithParams:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"stream", @"command", IdPhoto,@"IdPhoto", nil] onCompletion:^(NSDictionary *json) {
    //show the text in the label
    NSArray* list = [json objectForKey:@"result"];
    NSDictionary* photo = [list objectAtIndex:0];
    lblTitle.text = [photo objectForKey:@"title"];
}];
//load the big size photo
NSURL* imageURL = [api urlForImageWithId:IdPhoto isThumb:NO];
[photoView setImageWithURL: imageURL];
}
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
// Return YES for supported orientations
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
@end
```

Help

Comment: If you mean UDID then this is not possible. Use `identifierForVendor`.

Comment: would the message you suggested be applicable for handling a situation in which after we obtained the deviceid from a user, a snapstillimage message would trigger on the device of the user over a server?

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand your last comment.

Comment: Ok, I just wanted to know how to activate the snapStillImage message on another device. The last set of info was just a prequel to this: Would identifierForVendor still work? Updated question above

Comment: Sorry, no idea what "snapStillImage" is. Your question is unclear.

Comment: sorry. snapStillImage is a method that takes a picture and saves it to your photo album using the devices camera. It is part of the AVFoundation

Comment: From your code above, it seems it is actually your method, not part of `AVFoundation`. So your want the user to tap a button on one device, and call the method on the other. You could use `identifierForVendor` for that. Remember, that for `AVFoundation` to work, your app needs to be open, you cannot use the framework from the background.

Comment: Ok. There is an instance method in my app that makes sure a user is logged in so that shouldn't be an issue for now. Whats your recommendation for proceeding? Would you like to see some json, objective c, php to get a better idea of the intact api? I am interested to see the results of identifierForVendor after doing a little reading on it just now. Id still like to know how to get them instantiated so i can connect snapStillImage.

Comment: or rather where should i begin in the stack for writing the methods to handle this functionality? I already added an IdPhoto2 field in a separate table in the database to store the new photo. I also edited a function in my php api to retrieve idPhoto2 in the database using `query`.

Comment: The current query for IdPhoto is set to an NSUrl using json in the app. This url is set to the original image of the tapped picture and shown to the user that clicked it in fullscreen in a new view controller.

Comment: Should we start by eating the Json that calls the original photo? I am hoping we can fetch the user deviceid from the existing Json code block that calls the original image. I will post the segue that is triggered in the stream screen when an image is tapped, and also the result of the son call in my original post!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[UIDevice currentDevice] is just the shared instance (like a singleton) to get the object that contains the properties of the device you are on.  The name does not mean to imply that there are other devices (i.e. [UIDevice someOtherDevice]) that you can access.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/

Comment: whats your suggestion for accessing other devices properties programmatically? This was a difficult question to form. Like the Matrix or something.

Comment: One way would be to use Bluetooth to connect between devices and send a signal to another one, but it would require a "server" app (one that broadcasts a message) installed on one device and a "client" app (one that listens for a message) installed on the other device.

Comment: i will do more research on bluetooth

Comment: thank you for your help jeffrey but my last question to you is would my current mysql server count as the "server app" you mentioned previously.

Comment: Even though the question is solved, after a bit of research on core Bluetooth for iOS, I stumbled on this from github https://github.com/SocialObjects-Software/LGBluetooth based on your knowledge of Bluetooth, do you think the fundamental functionality of these peripherals and central could be set and accessed via the avcam method? (The link is of a core Bluetooth app for iOS)

Comment: We should probably move this to a new question, but for the first thing, no - your mysql server won't count as the server, because you want a device (device 1) to kick off a function on a second device (device 2) - right?

Comment: Secondly, that is a good find -- I'll check that project out.  I did a lot of beacon work (which uses greatly reduced Bluetooth functionality), and I can think of a number of ways I could do something similar just using beacons.  Yes, you can kick off the AVCam functionality using anything, but I think the app will need to be in the foreground for the device taking the photo.  Don't quote me on that though -- there may be a way to do it in the background; I've just never tried it before.  Definitely a cool idea...

Comment: Yes; according to Apple : `When your iOS app is in the background or in a suspended state, its Bluetooth-related capabilities are affected. By default, your app is unable to perform Bluetooth low energy tasks while it is in the background or in a suspended state. That said, if your app needs to perform Bluetooth low energy tasks while in the background, you can declare it to support one or both of the Core Bluetooth background execution modes (there’s one for the central role, and one for the peripheral role).`

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/AboutCoreBluetooth/Introduction.html

Comment: That's just for the Bluetooth part though.  The AVCam part would also have to work in the background, for the whole thing to work (when the app is backgrounded).  Otherwise, you could pop up a local notification, but someone would have to tap on that, which would launch the app and then take the picture.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your guidance so far . I will be asking a more detailed question in a bit after reading the entire core bluetooth overview